# Problem on Extremal Graphs: three independent paths

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

The problem states that:

> A simple (or strict) graph with $n$ vertices and $m>\dfrac{3(n-1)}{2}$ edges, has two vertex
>   joined by three independent paths.

Any hints, ideas or useful results, to attack this problem?

Comment: Are the edges undirected?

Comment: Yes, the graph is undirected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a key lemma which by itself may help you get started.

**Lemma.** Any graph with $n$ vertices and $m > \frac32 (n-1)$ edges either:

- is [$2$-vertex-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph), or
- has a subgraph with $n' < n$ vertices and $m' > \frac32(n'-1)$ edges.

**Proof.** Suppose the graph is not $2$-connected. Then there is a vertex $v$ such that the removal of $v$ leaves the graph disconnected. This means that we can partition the vertex set of the graph into a disjoint union $A \cup B \cup \{v\}$ (with $A,B \ne \varnothing$) such that there are no edges between $A$ and $B$.

If $A \cup \{v\}$ spans more than $\frac32 |A|$ edges, then it induces the subgraph we want. If $B \cup \{v\}$ spans more than $\frac32|B|$ edges, then it induces the subgraph we want. One of these has to happen: otherwise, the graph would contain at most $\frac32|A|+\frac32|B| = \frac32(n-1)$ edges, which violates the conditions of the lemma. $\square$

---

By the way, both the lemma and the result you want to prove are tight. When $m = \frac32(n-1)$, we have an infinite family of counterexamples known as the [friendship graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_graph) (shown below). If you don't read past the nice image taken from Wikipedia, you can still figure out the rest of the proof by yourself.

[image: Frienship graph]

If you do read on, then here's the rest of the solution.

The lemma lets us assume that the graph is $2$-connected. If not, we can keep passing to a smaller subgraph which satisfies the edge condition. But that can't keep happening forever, since $m > \frac32(n-1)$ means $\binom n2 > \frac32(n-1)$ which implies $n>3$. So eventually we end up in the first case of the lemma: at a subgraph which satisfies the edge condition and is $2$-connected.

Having $m > \frac32 (n-1)$ means $m>n$. This means the graph contains a cycle, which we'll call $C$.

If $C$ passes through all $n$ vertices, there must also be a non-cycle edge $vw$ (since there are more edges than just the $n$ edges along $C$). Now there are three independent paths from $v$ to $w$: by going clockwise around $C$, by going counterclockwise around $C$, and by the edge $vw$.

If $C$ passes through fewer than $n$ vertices, then (because the graph is connected) there must be a vertex $v$ with a neighbor $w$ outside $C$. Because the graph is $2$-connected, removing $v$ leaves a connected graph, so there must be a way to get from $w$ to $C$ not through $v$. Say the other path from $w$ to $C$ ends at a vertex $x$ of $C$. Then there are three independent paths from $v$ to $x$: by going clockwise around $C$, by going counterclockwise around $C$, and by going through $w$.

Comment: Does this lemma appear in a graph theory book? I've looked on Diestel's but did not find it. Can the lemma also be proved using the Global Version of Menger's Theorem?

Comment: The lemma seems far too specific to appear in a textbook, though I wouldn't be surprised if it were an exercise somewhere. The general idea of "pass to a subgraph which maximizes some density-related parameter" certainly appears in textbooks.